# Compiler memory allocation difference for nested loop against single loop

Tags: memory-management, compiler-optimization

I have two variations of doing a simple problem.
The problem is simple
we have to multiply each element of **pow2** with each element of **pow3** where both **pow2** and **pow3** are arrays carrying integers.

The code is in javascript (Node.js).
I am keeping both the arrays empty here and we can fill them up with different numbers while running.

**First one** :-

```
let pow3 = [], pow2 = [];
for (let i = 0; i < pow3.length; ++i) {
    for (let j = 0; j < pow2.length; j++) {
        let result = pow3[i] * pow2[j];
    }
}
```

**Second** :-

```
let pow3 = [], pow2 = [];
let j = 0, i = 0;
for (;;) {
    let result = pow3[i] * pow2[j];
    if (++i === pow3.length) {
        i = 0;
        j++;
    }
    if (j === pow2.length)
        break;
}
```

Now the time complexity is same if calculate in both the apporaches which is O(m*n) *m* and *n* being the length of arrays, but what I would like to know that will the actual run time be different in both cases as *approach-1* have 2 loops(nested) and *approach-2* have one single loop.
I want to know how the compiler will treat them differently.

Also we can replace multiple(2 or more) nested loops with a single loop with some carefully placed if and  else but will performance be effected or not?

I think most people are taking this question as mere complexity question so let me add some more clarification on this.
Here we are talking about **Loop optimisation (machine independent)** and in that too **Loop Jamming** because when nested loops are there *the locality of reference* is poor, which result in more time consumption as lot of memory switches are made while executing(theoretically). But due to lack of resources I am not particularly sure that whether this will effect the above scenario or not.

So if someone will answer in this perspective (compiler optimisation) I will really appreciate.

Comment: @MrSmith42 if it is that easy to it do on a modern computer please do it, and also share the steps please, it will be really helpful.

Comment: Here is why I am not able to do it,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54271755/why-the-execution-time-of-the-same-code-on-the-same-computer-could-be-different

Answer (score 0):

Your first approach is the best you'll be able to do for a while until you learn some really crazy algorithms (FFT, or Fast Fourier Transform, will be able to do this in `O((m+k)log(m+k))`, but that's very advanced). The second approach has the same time complexity, but is far more difficult to trace.

It's not the number of loops that affects your time complexity, but the number of times they execute relative to the bounds of the problem. In the second approach, you only have one loop, but to compensate that loop runs `nm` times.

Comment: Thanks for the reply :) 
I think most people are taking this question as mere complexity question so let me add some more clarification on this.
Here we are talking about **Loop optimisation (machine independent)** and in that too **Loop Jamming** because when nested loops are there *the locality of reference* is poor, which result in more time consumption as lot of memory switches are made while executing(theoretically). But due to lack of resources I am not particularly sure that whether this will effect the above scenario or not.