# CPU computation faster than MPS on PyTorch Tensors

Tags: pytorch, metal

I am learning deep learning with PyTorch, and I first started by getting used to tensors.
I wanted to compare `matmult` time between two matrices on the CPU and then on MPS, I used the following code (my chip is a M1 Pro from 2021):

```py
import time
import torch

device = "mps"

torch.manual_seed(1234)
TENSOR_A_CPU = torch.rand(50, 50)
TENSOR_B_CPU = torch.rand(50, 50)

torch.manual_seed(1234)
TENSOR_A_MPS = torch.rand(50, 50).to(device)
TENSOR_B_MPS = torch.rand(50, 50).to(device)

start_time = time.time()
torch.matmul(TENSOR_A_CPU, TENSOR_B_CPU)
print("CPU : --- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))

start_time = time.time()
torch.matmul(TENSOR_A_MPS, TENSOR_B_MPS)
print("MPS : --- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

and I got that :

```
CPU : --- 7.510185241699219e-05 seconds ---
MPS : --- 0.0003561973571777344 seconds ---
```

So as you can see the computation time is way lower on the CPU, but I thought it would be the opposite.
I am not sure but is MPS more optimized on other processes during the training process ? That would then justify using MPS, but if it's not the case I could just stay on the CPU for everything.

Thank you for your reading.

Comment: Know issue: https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/77799 Even with torch 2.X I see the same slow down when going for the MPS

Comment: Oh ok so it's not worth at all, thank you.

Comment: This is well known with GPUs, they are only faster if you put a large computational load, which you are not doing, it is not specific to pytorch or to MPS. It is not a programming problem either.

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE :**

Actually I had some issues in my code :

1. I've read that GPUs usually perform better with a "warm-up", so I added one.
2. The matrices I was multiplying were way too small to be representative.

So here is my updated code :

```py
import time
import torch

device = "mps"

torch.manual_seed(1234)
TENSOR_A_CPU = torch.rand(5000, 5000)
TENSOR_B_CPU = torch.rand(5000, 5000)

torch.manual_seed(1234)
TENSOR_A_MPS = torch.rand(5000, 5000).to(device)
TENSOR_B_MPS = torch.rand(5000, 5000).to(device)

# Warm-up
for _ in range(100):
    torch.matmul(torch.rand(500,500).to(device), torch.rand(500,500).to(device))
    
start_time = time.time()
torch.matmul(TENSOR_A_CPU, TENSOR_B_CPU)
print("CPU : --- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))

start_time = time.time()
torch.matmul(TENSOR_A_MPS, TENSOR_B_MPS)
print("MPS : --- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

and the results :

```
CPU : --- 0.154008150100708 seconds ---
MPS : --- 0.0034401416778564453 seconds ---
```

The computation complexity grows slower on the MPS, and on a lot of computations with gigantic matrices, it digs the difference.

Thanks again for reading.

Comment: That's interesting. My macbook air M1 doesn't seem to require the warm-up. By the way: CPU : --- 2.0386910438537598 seconds ---
MPS : --- 0.0010859966278076172 seconds --- Seems like my CPU is much slower than yours, and the GPU a bit faster.

Comment: I repeated the computation using Apple MLX. It yields --- 6.079673767089844e-05 seconds ---, which is way faster...

Comment: Every time I run this snippet I get different results. manual_seed is set, so time results shouldn't be constant?

Comment: @rumcajs it is normal: values are the same every time with the same seed, but the computation time will differ.

Comment: can you explain why or share some source with explanation?

Comment: @rumcajs here is another post dealing with that : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54271755/why-the-execution-time-of-the-same-code-on-the-same-computer-could-be-different